# Get all options from select box when options are o=constructed using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, html-select

I am trying to retrieve all the options from the dropdown list. I get all the options when they are manually constructed but I can't get them when constructed using ng-repeat.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = ["Emil", "Tobias", "Linus"];
    
     var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").options.length;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Found " + x + " options in the list.";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<p id="demo"></p>

<select id="mySelect" >
<option ng-repeat="x in names">{{x}}</option>
</select>


</div>
```

As you see when you run the snippet items found is returned as "0".

But the below snippet works if you construct options manually.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = ["Emil", "Tobias", "Linus"];
    
     var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").options.length;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Found " + x + " options in the list.";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<p id="demo"></p>

<select id="mySelect" >
<option >Emil</option>
<option >Tobias</option>
<option >Linus</option>
</select>


</div>
```

Would like to know how to get all the options  when ng-repeat it used with select. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is happening because your function executes before the `DOM` is rendered. Simply wrap your code inside `$timeout` and it will work as expected, as `$timeout` will execute your code only after `DOM` is rendered.

**Working Example:**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.names = ["Emil", "Tobias", "Linus"];
    $timeout(function () {
        var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").options.length;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Found " + x + " options in the list.";
    });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<p id="demo"></p>

<select id="mySelect" >
<option ng-repeat="x in names">{{x}}</option>
</select>


</div>
```

Comment: Gosh! Why didn't I think of that. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Mona happy to help you :-)

Comment: You can also do this:
```var x = $('#mySelect').options.length;
$('#mySelect').html("Found " + x + " options in the list.");```